# Загрузка нескольких изображений Django

Tags: python

недавно начал изучать джанго и столкнулся с проблемой - при попытке загрузке нескольких изображений к одному посту(я назвал класс поста History чтобы случайно не перепутать Post запрос и модель) сохраняется только одно, как это изменить и как должна тогда выглядеть форма и вывод данного поста на странице?

**models.py**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    first_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Album',  blank=True)
    second_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Album',  blank=True)
    third_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Album', blank=True)
    fourth_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Album', blank=True)


class History(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True, verbose_name="Название")
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст")
    level = IntegerRangeField(max_value=3, min_value=1, default=1, verbose_name="Уровень доступа")
    created_add = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создано в')
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    album = models.ImageField(Album, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'История'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Истории'
```

Что нужно прочитать чтобы разобраться в прикреплении нескольких картинок к одному посту? Я не про случаи, когда картинки выбираются из `ManyToMany` списка и когда создаётся отдельная модель `OneToOneField`, которую пользователь создаёт, потом выбирает в списке объектов для своего поста. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: `models.ImageField(Album` — вот здесь чушь какая-то написана, класс ImageField принимает первым аргументом функцию upload_to, а вы почему-то запихнули туда класс модели. Если вы хотите сделать связь с другой моделью, то для этого нужно делать ForeignKey или ManyToManyField

Comment: поле album типа ImageField, потому что где-то был подобный вопрос и там было написано, что это должен быть ImageField, а не ForeignKey/ManyToManyField/OneToOneFiled

Comment: Должно быть то, что вы хотите сделать. Если вы хотите картинку — тогда ImageField и выкиньте модель Album вообще. Если связь с моделью Album — тогда ForeignKey и забудьте про ImageField. А пытаться писать бессмысленный код, просто потому что где-то что-то было написано, — не надо

Comment: спасибо за совет, но если делать через ForeignKey, то пользователю будет доступен список всех альбомов и в будущем он не сможет найти свой альбом с фотографиями, а если делать через ImageField, то будет только 1 картинка или вы предлагаете сделать несколько полей с картинками и сделать их blank=True?

Comment: Отфильтруйте список альбомов, чтобы он был доступен не весь

Comment: Спасибо, а вы знаете как это делают в реальных проектах?

Comment: Для реального проекта в принципе странно хардкодить ровно четыре ImageField'а. Если есть цель добавления неопределённого количества изображений к одному посту, то для этого делается одна модель (например, HistoryImage), содержащая ForeignKey на модель поста History (связь «один ко многим»), и дальше пользователь может создавать несколько изображений путём создания объектов этой самой модели HistoryImage. А зачем тут нужен альбом — я не знаю